# Python console in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm currently working of Power BI with python scripting.
I'd like to print (using the function `print`) but I'm not able to find a way to see my printed message anywhere.

I've already search on Google and Stack Overflow if a console exists on Power BI to have the Python output

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset.loc[:1, 'access_token'])

access_token = dataset.iloc[0]
print(access_token)
```

I'd like to have the output of `print(access_token)`

Comment: Have you tried running power bi from cmd and watching that cmd? Can't try it now but just head over to the .exe and just run it pbi.exe and check run your python script while checking the output in the terminal window

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've finally found an efficient way to print debug in Python in Power BI.

As long as we cannot use the function `print` because we don't have a display of the standard output of Python in Power BI, we can raise exception in order to display a variable or anything else.

You can use `raise Exception(TheVariableYouWantToPrint`)`

For example, you can do `raise Exception(dataset)` if you want to check the content of the `dataset` global variable

You can also print a string like `raise Exception("Hello World")`

It's not the best way to print something but still, that's the only way I've found to do it easily and efficiently

Comment: But that will stop the script?

Comment: @ChadeeFouad yeah. But it doesn't matters since it's for "light" debugging purposes. I have read your suggestions, that's smart to use tkinter or file I/O. Still, I prefer to have an exception thrown/raised so I can follow the traceback of the script for example.

Answer (score 2):

***Sorry, no console***. But there are other ways to inspect your variables. Not using `print()` though. You haven't specified whether you're working with a `Python visual` directly on the `Report` tab, or the `Run Python Script` option under the `Transform` tab in the `Power Query Editor`. I'd suggest the latter.

Try this:

**1:** In the report tab, click  Click `Home > Enter Data > Load`  without inserting any data.

**2:** Click `Edit Queries` and select `Transform > Run Python Script`

**3:** Insert the following snippet in the dialog box:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I've just used some sample data since I don't have your `dataset`. The important thing here is that both df in my sample and dataset in your sample are of type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

**4:** Click `OK` and you should get this:

[image]

***Most*** variables (we'll get to that later) that you import or create should be made available there. In our case we have `d` and `df`. Click on `table` to the right of `df` to see this:

[image]

I hope this helps!

---

**End note:**

About the 'Most variables...' part. It seems that whether or not your variables are made available will depend on the datatype of said variable. I tried using a version of the snippet in your question and found that `access_token = df.iloc[0]` returns a variable of type `pandas.core.series.Series`. This will for some reason not be available for direct inspection as is the case for `d` and `df` that are of type `dict` and `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, respectively. So to make `access_token` availale to you, you should try `access_token = dataset.iloc[0].to_frame()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
Effectively I can fill dataset in order to print, but I've find a faster way to do it and above all, more in a console way :

I `raise Exception(WhatIWantToPrint)` and it display whatever I want through an exception, not the best, but perfect to check variables using the Pythin interpretor debugger

Comment: @Benjamin Audet Cool. Would you care to share your approach?

Comment: for example, I want to print all variables contained in the globals() of python
I do a `raise Exception(globals())` and it display the yellow block containing the exception

Comment: And about the access_token, I finally get it like this : `dataset.iloc[0, 0]`
If you are interested by the code : https://github.com/bimdata/BIMDataToPowerBI

Comment: @BenjaminAudet That's interesting. Please consider writing it up as an answer to your question. I'm sure it will attract an upvote or two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194487/discussion-between-benjamin-audet-and-vestland).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is making python in PBI open notepad and write whatever you need there from the df (while it's open) so that you could see what you need. Here's the code:

```
import os
f = open('foo.txt','w')
f.write('Hello world!')
f.close()
os.system("notepad.exe foo.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the easiest thing but should work. Use Tkinter to display a form with your message...something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()
HelloWorld = "HelloWorld   "
msg = tk.Message(master, text = HelloWorld )
msg.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 24, 'italic'))
msg.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

[image]